# Sort a character two-dimensional array using bubble sort alphabetically

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm newbie in C++ and i have a task to make a program that sorts 2d char array in alphabetic order along columns.I kinda know how to make it sort , but I have encountered an issue that is probably simple to solve , but i can't get what is the problem.When I go through loop in order to fill array with random characters everything seems to be ok . But as soon i try to print out value of single array element it gives out incorrect value.Hope someone could explain me what's the point.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqbtA.png)

```
void swap(char *xp, char *yp)  
{  
    char temp = *xp;  
    *xp = *yp;  
    *yp = temp;  
}

int main(){
    int n,m;
    bool finish = false;
    int i,j=0;
    char buff = 'a';
    
    cout<<"Rows amount : ";cin>>n;
    cout<<"Collon amount :";cin>>m;
    srand((time(0)));
    char arr[n][m];
    
    for( i=0;i<n;i++){
        for( j=0;j<m;j++){
            arr[n][m] = rand() % 25+97;
            cout<<arr[n][m]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"\n";

    for (i = 0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        if ((int)arr[j][i] > (int)arr[j+1][i])  
            swap(&arr[j][i], &arr[j+1][i]);
}
    

    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
```

Comment: Avoid magical number such as `97`, better to use `'a'`.

Comment: i mean, there are some issues with the code, but youre printing out `[n][m]` instead of `[i][j]`

Comment: You miss `'z'` as alphabet has 26 letters, not 25.

Comment: `char arr[n][m];` with runtime value is not valid C++ (VLA extension), use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Unrelated: [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: dont use random input for debugging and testing. Once you know that your code does the right thing for one test case you can try a second test case, then more, when you know it works you can turn to random input again. When testing and debugging you want reproducability (not only within a second)

Comment: you could generate random input once and then use that for repeated test, or use a fixed seed.

Comment: There are some problems with your question. First, you seem to have `using namespace std;` which is not recommended and in combination with defining your own `swap` it can have unexpected consequences. Second, It is unclear how you got the output in the image from that code. You have a 2d array of random characters and thats what you would see on the output: https://godbolt.org/z/7aoM7K Are you sure that the code you posted is the code that produces the output in the image? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Tell me in your own words what arr[j][i] means?

Comment: I don't think you first loop is doing what you think it is doing. Look carefully at your indices.